# How to have multiple keys referencing one value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS value provider :

```
myApp.value('myValueProvider',
{
    'k1': 'v1',
    'k2': 'v2',
    'k3': 'v2'
});
```

Where 'v2' is a complex Object so I don't want to duplicate every v2 values from k2 to k3.

So my goal is to obtain something like this:

```
myApp.value('myValueProvider',
{
    'k1': 'v1',
    'k2': 'v2',
    'k3': myValueProvider.k2
});
```

Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: well... if it's json, no, you can't because JSON is a string. If it is an object, you can get a reference to the object and store it in both locations.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  what do you mean, "`v2` is a complex JSON Object"?  what you are showing here are strings, not objects.  Also, there are no "JSON Objects",  JSON is a way to represent Objects as strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
// create the complex object that you want to assign to multiple properties
var complexObj = {
    ... your complex obj props ...
};

// create the provider object and assign the complex object reference to multiple properties
var valueProviderObj = {
    k1: 'v1',
    k2: complexObj,
    k3: complexObj
};

// associate the provider object to the angular value by key name
myApp.value('myValueProvider', valueProviderObj);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Added comments explaining what the code does and how it relates to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can change it in `run` stage.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.value('myValueProvider',
{
    'k1': 'v1',
    'k2': 'v2'
});

myApp.run(function(myValueProvider) {
  myValueProvider.k3 = myValueProvider.k2;
});

myApp.controller('ctrl', function(myValueProvider) {
  console.log('from controller', myValueProvider);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl"></div>
```